# Sort posts by number of times tagged

Tags: wp-query, tags, order

Let's say I have a custom post type Books, and I tag the books with a custom taxonomy "Person". The taxonomy contains the name of a person and basically means the person has read that particular book.

So, a book can obviously be tagged with multiple "Persons".

I wanna list Books and order them by the number of "Persons" that have read it. Basically, count the number of "Person" tags, and order the Books by that.

I'm reading the documentation on wp_query but don't see a way to do this. Is it doable?

Comment: did you mean, you want to sort post that have more "person" selected first ?

Comment: @rudtek Yup, that appears to be the same or at least a similar issue. Cheers.